# Get page content using slug

Tags: plugin-development, php, pages, slug

I'm trying to get page content when I only know the slug string.

Is there a function for this, or an easy way to do this or is this a case of doing it via SQL?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and the parameter `name` which is the slug:

```
$page = get_posts([ 'name' => 'your-slug' ]);

if ( $page )
{
    echo $page[0]->post_content;
}
```

Be aware that the post type in `get_posts()` defaults to `'post'`. If you want a **page** use …

```
$page = get_posts([
    'name'      => 'your-slug',
    'post_type' => 'page'
]);
```

If you want **all** public post types (except attachments) set the post type argument to `'any'`. Then you could get more than one result because slugs are not unique across different post types.

Answer (score 5):

### If on the page with the slug in question

Read up on [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):
[`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) also takes the slug as an argument.

Hence,

```
if( is_page( 'your-slug' ) ) {
     // fetch content
}
```

will do what you want.

### If on another page

Should you be interested on how to fetch post/page content based on a slug when *not* on said page, you can feed [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) a slug as well. This is not documented in the codex.

The following will fetch the id from a slug:

```
$args = array(
    'name' => 'your-slug'
);
$posts_from_slug = get_posts( $args );

// echo fetched content
echo $posts_from_slug[0]->post_content;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get a page by its title using [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) function.

**You can use it like this (assuming you want to show the content):**

```
$page = get_page_by_title('Your Title'); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
echo $content;
```

**BTW, to Get page using slug:**

```
function get_page_id_by_slug($slug){
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '".$slug."'AND post_type = 'page'");
    return $id;
}

$page = get_post(get_page_id_by_slug('my-slug'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `get_page_by_path` to retrieve the WP_Post object, then you can extract the post content and filter for HTML output if necessary.

**Syntax**

```
get_page_by_path( string $page_path, string $output = OBJECT, string|array $post_type = 'page' )
```

**Example:**

I use this code when populating a theme template from a page, to ensure the content is rendered as HTML:

```
<?php
$about = get_page_by_path('about'); 
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $about->post_content ); 
echo $content;
?>
```

To get a post of a different type, pass in the other two parameters:

```
get_page_by_path('cat', OBJECT, 'animal');
```

for more reference see [WordPress Function Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path)

[image: Parameters]